# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError -org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader when upgrade to Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

EDIT: I have updated this to issue with Spring boot 3 upgrade. I am trying to upgrade from 2.7.13 to Spring boot 3. I had Spring Security 5.8.4 recently and had made the Spring Security changes. The app was running with 2.7.13 with spring security 5.8.4.
Now that i have changed to spring boot 3, I have issues with upgrading spring cloud.

UPDATE as of July 10th, i have cleaned up the dependency management but
my securityConfig.java still points to the old @EnableWebSecurity (5.7.7

So here are my relevant versions and pieces of the pom (UPDATED July 10th):

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.8</version>
    <relativePath/>
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
//I want to share I have modules that also have a pom in each but they only have spring-booot-starter-web in their dependencies block without specifying version.
<modules>
    <module>module1</module>
    <module>module2</module>
    <module>module3</module>
    <module>app</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <google-cloud-gcp-dependencies.version>4.5.1</google-cloud-gcp-dependencies.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    <jsoup.version>1.10.2</jsoup.version>
    <h2.version>1.4.200</h2.version>
    <apache-common-text>1.10.0</apache-common-text>
    <modelmapper.version>2.3.5</modelmapper.version>
    <com.jayway.jsonpath.version>2.6.0</com.jayway.jsonpath.version>
    <flyway-core.version>9.5.1</flyway-core.version>
    <spring-cloud-function.version>4.0.0</spring-cloud-function.version>
    <postgresql.version>42.4.3</postgresql.version>
    <snakeyaml.version>1.32</snakeyaml.version>
    <properties>


        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${google-cloud-gcp-dependencies.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencyManagement>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-binder</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
                <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring6</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

Here is my relevant spring dependencies. There is postgres and h2 dependency and a 3rd party dependency too (which i've removed any deprecated methods) but i won't list here if not necessary.

Comment: Spring Boot 3.x requires JDK 17, which uses new Java EE packages instead of Jakarta.

Comment: Hi Duffy, I am using JDK 17. I read that we can stay using spring boot 2.7.13 while using Spring Security 6. 

Spring Framework 6 requires Java 17 and Jakarta EE 9 and is compatible with the recently released Jakarta EE 10. 
i am trying to take 1 step at a time and get this running before i use spring boot 3.

Comment: The problem is that JDK 17 removed Jakarta.  They are no longer available to you, regardless of your version of Spring.

Comment: then isn't that a huge conflict? if spring boot 3 requires spring security 6 which requires JDK 17 and Jakarta.

Comment: Conflict?  Not for Spring 3.x users.  They make it clear what their requirement is.  Your assumption of Spring Boot 2.7 and Spring Security 6.x seems to be the problem.  You thought you could do it in steps.  Not so.  Go for Spring Boot 3.x and JDK 17 now.

Comment: I see. I have changed to the spring-boot-starter-parent to 3.0.0, also 3.0.7 but when i do that I am getting 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.forDefaultResourceLocation(java.lang.ClassLoader)'

It doesn't tell me which method.

Comment: @duffymo, i dont need graalvm to run spring boot 3 right?

Comment: No, just JDK 17.

Comment: Spring Security 6 requires, Spring Framework 6. Which is JakartaEE only. You cannot use Spring Security 6 with Spring Boot 2.x, you would need to upgrade Spring Boot as well. The fact that you are upgrading only spring boot makes me fear you are managing a lot of dependencies yourself instead of using the tested ones from the starters and managed by Spring Boot / Spring Cloud. If you intend to upgrade to Spring Boot 3 please show your pom.xml/build.gradle so that can be cleaned up (made proper so to say).

Comment: @M.Deinum, I will show the pom soon. I want to ask, if you change to Spring Boot 3, it wont automatically updating to Spring Framework 6 right?
Sorry i am upgrading first time.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I added the pom info

Comment: For starters remove the `spring-security` dependencies, those are part of `spring-boot-starter-security`. Remove `persistence-api` (already in `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and the `servlet-api` can be gone as well. Another thing is you are using Google Cloud and Spring Cloud (and friends) are tied to specific Spring Boot versions, make sure that is compatible with the Spring Cloud/Boot versions you have in your project. If this doesn't work please include the **full stacktrace** in your question.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum, I have new updated my post to relevant error. Now i get Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/PersistenceContext. .BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesBeans' (Full details in the main post). I have updated my pom.xml to include anything that was pointing to previous versions to newer versions. I dont find anywhere that i am using javax.persistence.PersistenceContext

Comment: You are using Spring Boot why are you updating individual dependencies? You should be using the Spring Boot starters for your dependencies. All in all it feels like you are trying to outsmart the dependency management. You are also using Spring Cloud which is tied to certain Spring Boot versions. If you upgrade Spring Boot you need to upgrade Spring Cloud as well (which judging from the error you didn't).

Comment: I can remove spring framework individual dependencies but they will point back to version 5. shouldnt it be 6?
Also I have upgaded spring cloud as it was 2021.0.2 and now it is 2022.0.0. I also upgraded google-cloud-gcp-dependencies.version from 3.0.0 to 4.5.1 and  spring-cloud-function.version from 3.27 to 4.0.0

Comment: @M.Deinum, when i removed those framework dependencies, i will back to the original NoSuchMethodError and the first error i get is:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.forDefaultResourceLocation(java.lang.ClassLoader)' without further details. so first thing i do checked was the org.springframework.core.io which was using 5.3.25 versions. That is why I updated individual dependences.

Comment: Do you know why the starter parents are not using version 6 ? When I specified each individual dependency to use version 6 or 3, then i was move onto the current error above. Unless the parent can pick up the new versions, it seems I have to use these individual ones..

Comment: No you should **not** use the individual ones as that will lead to all sorts of other issues. As stated you are also using Spring Cloud which is tied to certain Spring Boot versions. If you upgrade Spring Boot you also must upgrade Spring Cloud. I suspect you haven't. The Spring Boot 3.0 parent already has all the needed dependencies in the correct versions.

Comment: Spring Cloud Function 3.2 is for Spring Boot 2.6/2.7 you will need to upgrade to the 4.x line. This probably applies to the google stuff as well. As mentioned you need to upgrade Spring Cloud as well.

Comment: @M.Deinum, in the pom, i forgot to mention, i have already have these: (updated above) spring-cloud-dependencies, pring-cloud-function-core, spring-cloud-function-context. 
I am using spring-cloud-function.version>4.0.0

Comment: Your `pom` dependencies should go in `<dependencyManagement><dependencies>` **not** in `<dependencies>`. Still you shouldn't need nor add those other dependencies. The fact tha tyou need to do that indicates there is something really wrong with the way you structured and use your project. Also the idea of those `pom` dependencies is that you don't need to specify versions for the dependencies that are managed by that `pom` dependency, so only import the pom and ditch the other `spring-cloud` stuff versions.

Comment: @M.Deinum,  I actually have spring frame work security and spring cloud in     </dependencyManagement>. The others dependency such as oauth2, starter-config, cloud secretmanager, spring-security-core is under dependencies. 

let me update the above.

Comment: Again don't add the individual versions you should only have the starters... If you need the individual versions you are doing it wrong, you should be fixing that problem not just slapping some dependencies in there until the problem goes away. Those dependencies wiill haunt you for a long time, especially when you start upgrading, you suddently have old incompatible versions and you need to do it again. Only add the starters, they should be dependencies and not in dependency management, ditch the indiviual dependencies. The error you have indicates an incompatible Spring Cloud version.

Comment: i have updated what is under dependencyManagement and what is under dependencies

Comment: @M.Deinum, inside spring-boot-starter does have org.springframework.spring-core 6.0.2, but my repo is still reading 5.x version. Is  this an intellij issue? I have tried deleting .idea and reopening but that does not work.

Comment: Again/still you are trying to much. Ditch the spring security dependencies as well as the spring-cloud ones keep only the `pom` related ones in `dependencyManagement`.

Comment: can you do a response on that and show me an example? i don't understand what you mean by ditching all the spring cloud and spring security in dependencies and keeping only the pom related ones. Dont follow. Reason is if i remove any spring cloud, my app wont detect those imports. Sorry donrt follow,

Also, i read that dependencyManagement's purpose is to use a a version and you still need dependencies part for the actual dependency.

Comment: Your update suddenly shows Thymeleaf, you also mention a 3rd party dependency. Hence your information isn't complete, how do you expect an answer if you don't give all the relevant information. **all dependencies** are relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

You are managing too much, that is already being managed by the starters and imports.

```xml
properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <google-cloud-gcp-dependencies.version>4.5.1</google-cloud-gcp-dependencies.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    <jsoup.version>1.10.2</jsoup.version>
    <h2.version>1.4.200</h2.version>
    <apache-common-text>1.10.0</apache-common-text>
    <modelmapper.version>2.3.5</modelmapper.version>
    <com.jayway.jsonpath.version>2.6.0</com.jayway.jsonpath.version>
    <flyway-core.version>9.5.1</flyway-core.version>
    <postgresql.version>42.4.3</postgresql.version>
    <snakeyaml.version>1.32</snakeyaml.version>
<properties>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.8</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
      <version>${google-cloud-gcp-dependencies.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  <dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.12.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit</artifactId>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

- `spring-boot-starter-security` already pulls in the Spring Security dependencies, no need to define them again. Not in `dependencyManagement` nor as `dependencies`
- The `bom` (the `pom` with scope `import`) are there to manage the depenendency versions, no need to specify them again. The Spring Cloud one will manage the Spring Cloud Function versions.
- Upgrade to Spring Boot 3.0.8 to have the latest 3.0 release, the same for Spring Cloud.

Comment: I had updated my original post above and updated the pom.xml info. 
I have cleaned up other spring security framework the dependency management but
my securityConfig.java still points to the old @EnableWebSecurity (5.7.7)

Comment: even when i bypass the security issue by adding    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency> inside dependencyManagement, I still get noSuchMEthodError where org.springframework.core is still pointing to 5.3.25

Comment: Again **don't mess around with individual dependencies**. Spring Boot already manages Spring Security for you. The error you get is impossible to get with the dependencies you have shown here, so that means you have more dependencies that you aren't showing, hence your question and the information is incomplete. And no it is not pointing to 5.3 the error you last posted indicates you are using an incompatible Spring Cloud version. Looking at the update you suddenly introduce Thymeleaf, for which you should use `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` instead of a single dependency.

Comment: Yes, I will park this question and stop. I have a third party application that i've found that it is using those Spring framework 5.x.x.. and Spring Boot 2.7.x Thank you for your support.