Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader
I have a microservice architecture spring boot services. I'm trying to upgrade version from 2.x.x to 3.3.0 but facing NoSuchMethodError.
Below is my parent and child build.gradle files. Please help to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.
This is parent build.gradle file
 buildscript {
    ext.versions = [
            "springBootVersion"             : "3.3.0",
            "mongodbBsonVersion"            : "4.7.2",
            "commonsIoVersion"              : "2.11.0",
            "modelmapperVersion"            : "3.1.0",
            "httpclientcoreVersion"         : "4.4.15",
            "httpclientVersion"             : "4.5.13",
            "tomcatVersion"                 : "9.0.68",
            "jaspytSpringBootStarterVersion": "3.0.4",
            "lombokVersion"                 : "1.18.24",
            "log4j2Version"                 : "2.19.0"
    ]

    ext.deps = [

            "spring_boot_starter_web_plugin"       : "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${versions.springBootVersion}",
            "spring_boot_starter_data_plugin"      : "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:${versions.springBootVersion}",
            "spring_boot_starter_data_jpa_plugin"  : "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${versions.springBootVersion}",
            "spring_boot_starter_security_plugin"  : "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:${versions.springBootVersion}",
            "spring_boot_starter_validation_plugin": "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:${versions.springBootVersion}",
            "spring_boot_starter_actuator_plugin"  : "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:${versions.springBootVersion}",

            "jaspytSpringBootStarter_plugin"       : "com.github.ulisesbocchio:jasypt-spring-boot-starter:${versions.jaspytSpringBootStarterVersion}",
            "lombok_plugin"                        : "org.projectlombok:lombok:${versions.lombokVersion}",

            "mongodb_bson_plugin"                  : "org.mongodb:bson:${versions.mongodbBsonVersion}",
            "commons_Io_plugin"                    : "commons-io:commons-io:${versions.commonsIoVersion}",
            "modelmapper_plugin"                   : "org.modelmapper:modelmapper:${versions.modelmapperVersion}",
            "httpclientcore_plugin"                : "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:${versions.httpclientcoreVersion}",
            "httpclient_plugin"                    : "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:${versions.httpclientVersion}",
            "spring_boot_test_plugin"              : "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${versions.springBootVersion}",
            "tomcat_embed_core_plugin"             : "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${versions.tomcatVersion}",
            "tomcat_embed_websocket_plugin"        : "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:${versions.tomcatVersion}",
            "tomcat_embed_annotations_plugin"      : "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api:${versions.tomcatVersion}",
            "log4j2_api_plugin"                    : "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:${versions.log4j2Version}",
            "log4j2_sl4j_plugin"                   : "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:${versions.log4j2Version}",
            "json-smart"                           : "net.minidev_json-smart:2.4.10",
            "jakarta_servlet"                      : "jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:6.0.0",
            "jakarta_validation"                   : "jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:3.1.0"
    ]

    dependencies {
        classpath files("libs/common-logging-utility-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar")
    }

}

plugins {
    id "com.palantir.docker" version "0.35.0"
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.1.0"
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "3.3.0"
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

}

This is first child build.gradle file
plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.7"
    id "jacoco"
    id "net.researchgate.release" version "2.8.0"
}

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'com.palantir.docker'

dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }

    implementation deps.tomcat_embed_core_plugin
    implementation deps.tomcat_embed_websocket_plugin
    implementation deps.tomcat_embed_annotations_plugin
    implementation deps.spring_boot_starter_data_plugin
    implementation deps.spring_boot_starter_security_plugin
    implementation deps.spring_boot_starter_validation_plugin
    implementation deps.spring_boot_starter_actuator_plugin
    implementation deps.jaspytSpringBootStarter_plugin
    implementation deps.mongodb_bson_plugin
    implementation deps.commons_Io_plugin
    implementation deps.modelmapper_plugin
    implementation  deps.httpclient_plugin
    implementation  deps.httpclientcore_plugin
    implementation deps.log4j2_api_plugin
    implementation deps.log4j2_sl4j_plugin
    implementation deps.jakarta_validation
    compileOnly deps.lombok_plugin
    compileOnly deps.jakarta_servlet
    annotationProcessor deps.lombok_plugin
    testImplementation deps.spring_boot_test_plugin
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.4.2.Final'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final'
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:0.2.0"
    implementation files("../libs/common-logging-utility-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar")
    implementation group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-identity', version: '1.11.1'
    implementation group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-security-keyvault-secrets', version: '4.2.2'
    implementation group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-codec', version: '4.1.100.Final'
    implementation group: 'net.minidev', name: 'json-smart', version: '2.4.10'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-beans', version: '5.3.23'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '5.3.23'
    implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '30.0-jre'
    implementation group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-ui', version: '1.7.0'
    implementation group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-codec-http2', version: '4.1.100.Final'
    implementation group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20231013'
//    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-autoconfigure', version: '3.0.7'

}
configurations {
    implementation.exclude module: 'dom4j'
}

bootJar {
    mainClass.set('com.yta.connect.bytr.api.BytrApiApplication')
}

jar {
    enabled = true
    archiveFileName = 'backend-service'
}

task prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel {
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.required = true
    }
}
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

This is second child build.gradle file
plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.7"
    id "jacoco"
    id "net.researchgate.release" version "2.8.0"
}

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'com.palantir.docker'

dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    implementation deps.tomcat_embed_core_plugin
    implementation deps.tomcat_embed_websocket_plugin
    implementation deps.tomcat_embed_annotations_plugin
    implementation deps.spring_boot_starter_data_plugin
    implementation deps.spring_boot_starter_actuator_plugin
    implementation deps.mongodb_bson_plugin
    implementation deps.commons_Io_plugin
    implementation deps.modelmapper_plugin
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:4.1.2'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.1.2'
    implementation  deps.httpclient_plugin
    implementation  deps.httpclientcore_plugin
    implementation deps.jakarta_validation
    compileOnly deps.lombok_plugin
    compileOnly deps.jakarta_servlet
    implementation deps.log4j2_api_plugin
    implementation deps.log4j2_sl4j_plugin
    implementation files("../libs/common-logging-utility-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar")
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat', name: 'jackson-dataformat-csv', version: '2.14.2'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.14.2'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.14.2'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.14.2'
    annotationProcessor deps.lombok_plugin
    testImplementation deps.spring_boot_test_plugin
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.4.2.Final'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final'
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:0.2.0"
    implementation group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-storage-queue', version: '12.20.1'
    implementation 'com.azure:azure-core:1.39.0'
    implementation group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-storage-blob', version: '12.20.0'
    implementation group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-messaging-servicebus', version: '7.10.1'
    implementation group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'azure-storage', version: '8.6.6'
    implementation group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-identity', version: '1.9.2'
    implementation group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-security-keyvault-secrets', version: '4.2.2'
    implementation group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-codec', version: '4.1.100.Final'
    implementation group: 'net.minidev', name: 'json-smart', version: '2.4.10'
    implementation group: 'org.dom4j', name: 'dom4j', version: '2.1.3'
    implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '30.0-jre'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-compress', version: '1.21'
    implementation group: 'xerces', name: 'xercesImpl', version: '2.12.2'
    implementation group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-ui', version: '1.7.0'
    implementation 'com.opencsv:opencsv:5.7.1'
    implementation group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-codec-http2', version: '4.1.100.Final'
    implementation group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20231013'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-beans', version: '5.3.23'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '5.3.23'
}



bootJar {
    mainClass.set('com.byt.connect.collection.BytrCollectionServiceApplication')
}

jar {
    enabled = true
    archiveFileName = 'collection-service'
}

task prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel {
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.required = true
    }
}
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

Error log
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.forDefaultResourceLocation(java.lang.ClassLoader)'
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:483)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:479)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:294)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:274)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352)


seems to be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76632274/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-core, you are managing too many dependencies that should be managed by spring boot (for example spring-core)
